# Status function bar - C

Tags: c, function, progress-bar, statusbar

I have this function:

```
void choiceTwo(void){

    system("clear");
    printf("================ RUN ALL FUNCTION ================\n\n");

    printf("\nTest case 'create/destroy'... ");
    fflush(stdout);
    test_create_destroy();
    printf("OK\n");

    printf("Test case 'add/remove edge'... ");
    fflush(stdout);
    test_add_remove_edge();
    printf("OK\n");

    printf("Test case 'print graph'... ");
    fflush(stdout);
    test_print_graph();
    printf("OK\n");

    printf("Test case 'null'... ");
    fflush(stdout);
    test_null();
    printf("OK\n");

    printf("\nPress enter to continue ");
    getchar();
    getchar();
    main();
}
```

How can I print the status of this function by using a progress bar (in percent) like this in the picture?

[Status Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0moq.png)

I tried to do this using python, but do not know how to fully control the function status

Comment: Since you deleted your question [C — fix matrix dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44358154/) before I could answer, I'm stuck with using a comment on an unrelated question of yours to point you at the code in https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-4435-8154 — which is what I was about to post when I was notified that you'd deleted the question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler    I'm really sorry!!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void working ( int showat, int done, int total) {
    char dash[51]  = "--------------------------------------------------";
    char blank[51] = "                                                  ";
    int portion = 0;
    float percent = 0.0f;

    printf ( "\033[?25l");//hide cursor
    printf ( "\033[38;5;10m");//green text
    printf ( "\033[48;5;0m");//on black
    printf ( "\033[%d;H", showat);//move curson to line showat
    percent = ( (float)done * 100) / total;
    portion = percent / 2.0f;
    printf ( "Progress: [\033[38;5;0m\033[48;5;10m");//black text on green
    printf ( "%.*s\033[38;5;10m\033[48;5;0m%.*s]%6.1f%% Complete\r"//back to green text on black
    , portion, blank, 50 - portion, dash, percent);

    printf ( "\033[0m");//reset color
    printf ( "\033[?25h");//show cursor
}

void test_progress ( ) {
    int item = 0;
    int allitems = 200;
    //do things in functioin where you need to show progress
    for ( item = 0; item <= allitems; item++) {
        working ( 5, item, allitems);
        usleep ( 50000);
    }
}

void test_loop ( ) {
    int item = 0;
    int allitems = 500;
    //do things in functioin where you need to show progress
    for ( item = 0; item <= allitems; item++) {
        working ( 9, item, allitems);
        usleep ( 50000);
    }
}

void choiceTwo(void){

    printf ( "\033[2J");//clear screen
    printf ( "\033[0;H");//move curson to line 0
    printf("================ RUN PROGRESS TEST ================\n\n");

    printf("\nTest progress'... ");
    test_progress();
    printf("\nOK\n");


    printf("\nTest loop'... ");
    test_loop();
    printf("\nOK\n");

}

int main()
{
    choiceTwo ( );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The precision field, `%.precision`, will let you print a specific number of characters. An asterisk will allow the use of a variable. `%.*s` will print `done` number of characters from the `x` array, then `50 - done` characters from the `dash` array.
Using a carriage return, `\r`, should keep printing the loop on the same line as the loop progresses.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int loop = 1;
    int done = 0;
    int end = 200000;
    char dash[51] = "--------------------------------------------------";
    char x[51] =    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    float percent = 0.0f;
    while ( loop <= end) {
        percent = ( (float)loop * 100) / end;
        done = percent / 2.0f;
        printf ( "Progress: [%.*s%.*s]%6.1f%% Complete\r", done, x, 50 - done, dash, percent);
        loop++;
    }
    printf ( "\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If your terminal supports escape codes, this may be used to achieve the colors indicated in the image.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int loop = 1;
    int done = 0;
    int end = 200000;
    char dash[51]  = "--------------------------------------------------";
    char blank[51] = "                                                  ";
    float percent = 0.0f;
    printf ( "\033[?25l");//hide cursor
    printf ( "\033[38;5;10m");//green text
    printf ( "\033[48;5;0m");//on black
    while ( loop <= end) {
        percent = ( (float)loop * 100) / end;
        done = percent / 2.0f;
        printf ( "Progress: [\033[38;5;0m\033[48;5;10m");//black text on green
        printf ( "%.*s\033[38;5;10m\033[48;5;0m%.*s]%6.1f%% Complete\r"//back to green text on black
        , done, blank, 50 - done, dash, percent);
        loop++;
    }
    printf ( "\033[0m");//reset color
    printf ( "\033[?25h");//show cursor
    printf ( "\n");
    return 0;
}
```

this wraps the progress in a function. call this function with the line you want the bar shown on ( 0 to 23), the items done so far and the total items.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void working ( int showat, int done, int total) {
    char dash[51]  = "--------------------------------------------------";
    char blank[51] = "                                                  ";
    int portion = 0;
    float percent = 0.0f;

    printf ( "\033[?25l");//hide cursor
    printf ( "\033[38;5;10m");//green text
    printf ( "\033[48;5;0m");//on black
    printf ( "\033[%d;H", showat);//move curson to line showat
    percent = ( (float)done * 100) / total;
    portion = percent / 2.0f;
    printf ( "Progress: [\033[38;5;0m\033[48;5;10m");//black text on green
    printf ( "%.*s\033[38;5;10m\033[48;5;0m%.*s]%6.1f%% Complete\r"//back to green text on black
    , portion, blank, 50 - portion, dash, percent);

    printf ( "\033[0m");//reset color
    printf ( "\033[?25h");//show cursor
}

int main()
{
    int loop = 1;
    int end  = 20000;
    while ( loop <= end) {
        working ( 23, loop, end);
        loop++;
    }
    printf ( "\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But, how can I print the printf one at a time during the continuance of the bar? @xing

Comment: I add the `printf ( "\033[8;H");` in the loop ?

Comment: I printf to the line 547, I wrote `printf (" \ 033 [547; H ");` but the progress bar is split, one on top of the terminal and one at the bottom, and only that during low flows. And only when it reaches 100% print the things after

Comment: using the `printf ( "\033[0;H");`, the bar is printing on the top of the terminal

Comment: Can you give me a code example? Because I do not understand.

Comment: [code primary function](https://pastebin.com/raw/BghKrWj4)                          [test_create_destroy()](https://pastebin.com/raw/4C9Xs1zk)